# Customize dataKey values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bar-chart, recharts

I have just started out using Recharts and am a total beginner. I have managed to render a chart, customise some styling, such as color of the bars and position of the legend, but I am now struggling to customise the dataKey values.

At the moment, the chart looks like this:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/glBKE.png

I am trying to render a BarChart from the following data:

```
const data = [
{day: "2020-07-01", kilogram: 80, calories: 240},
{day: "2020-07-02", kilogram: 80, calories: 240},
{day: "2020-07-03", kilogram: 80, calories: 240},
{day: "2020-07-04", kilogram: 80, calories: 240},
{day: "2020-07-05", kilogram: 80, calories: 240}
];
```

Setting the dataKey on the `<XAxis>` component to "day" works fine, but the ticks display the full string. Instead, I would like to only display the day of the month. So **instead of saying "2020-07-01", it should only say "1"**.

I have already tried the following two things:

1. I have added this function to the render method, to calculate the day and set this as the dataKey value.

```
  let dataKeyValue = (x) => {
     let value = x.day;
     value = value.getDate();
     value = value.toString();
     return value;
  };
```

2. I have added this method to the component, to format the tick.

```
 axisTickFormatter(day) {
    const date = new Date(day);
    const dataKey = date.getDate();
    dataKey.toString();
    console.log(typeof dataKey);
    return dataKey;
 }
```

*=> you can see both in the code below - commented out*

This is my code:

```
class Chart extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.type = this.props.type;
    this.data = this.props.data;
  }

// axisTickFormatter(day) {
  //   const date = new Date(day);
  //   const dataKey = date.getDate();
  //   dataKey.toString();
  //   console.log(typeof dataKey);
  //   return dataKey;
  // }

render() { 
    // let dataKeyValue = (x) => {
    //   let value = x.day;
    //   value = value.getDate();
    //   value = value.toString();
    //   return value;
    //};
      return (
        <ResponsiveContainer>
          <BarChart
            width={730}
            height={250}
            data={this.data.sessions}
            barCategoryGap={8}
            barSize={7}
          >
            <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="2 2" vertical={false} />
            <XAxis dataKey="day" />
            {/* <XAxis dataKey={(day) => this.axisTickFormatter(day)} /> */}
            {/* <XAxis dataKey={dataKeyValue} /> */}
            <YAxis />
            <Tooltip />
            <Legend
              iconSize={8}
              iconType="circle"
              verticalAlign="top"
              align="right"
            />
            <Bar dataKey="kilogram" fill="#282D30" radius={[3, 3, 0, 0]} />
            <Bar dataKey="calories" fill="#E60000" radius={[3, 3, 0, 0]} />
          </BarChart>
        </ResponsiveContainer>
       )
    }

}
```

Could you give me a hint as to what I am forgetting or doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Christine, welcome to StackOverflow!

What would be really helpful for such a case is a working example, e.g. with jsfiddle or StackOverflow's code snippet tool :) .

I'm not an expert with `recharts` specifically but it looks like `XAxis` only takes the key, not the actual value. What that means in turn is, that you would have to modify your data before passing it into the `BarChart` component.

The approach you already have, reading the date and getting the day, looks valid, though.

Maybe you can try the following:

```
    function formatDate(input) {
      return new Date(input).getDate();
      
      // alternatively you can also just use the last two characters from that string with 
      // return input.slice(-2);
    }

    class Chart extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.type = this.props.type;

        // change the date to the desired format, but keep all the others value as they are
        this.data = this.props.data.map(d => {
          day: formatDate(d.day),
          kilogram: d.kilogram,
          calories: d.calories
        });
      }
```